# Facebook Like button and backdated posts on Tumblr

Tags: facebook-like, tumblr, posts

I've implemented the facebook like button in my tumblr project - and it works well. However, one thing I have noticed is that when I backdate a post, ie so I can change the order the way it appears on the site, the facebook like button no longer works for that particular post. I've used the lint/debugger and it's not throwing any errors and there's been no change in the  coding as it's been called in a loop and the facebook like button works for other posts. So does anybody know what's going on or if this is an issue I need to be aware of?

Comment: Links? Examples? Add a URL to the site? Maybe boil this down to a minimal case example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was general problems between Tumblr and Facebook in the last days

but now it should work fine,

if you still get general problems then you can report about them as a comment in the main bug report here:
http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/134909119955013

and a link to your blog will be helpful.